# Difference between position of 'if's in pattern matching

Tags: scala, if-statement, pattern-matching

Is there a difference between the following two ways of pattern matching:

```
foo match {
case a if(cond) => println("bar")
case a => println("baz")
case _ => println("default") 
}
```

and

```
foo match {
case a => if (cond) println("bar") else println("baz")
case _ => println("default") 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of what you are trying to accomplish, there is no difference. But semantically there is a difference in what you're actually doing.

In the first case, you have a pattern with a guard suffix (the condition). The guard is evaluated *only if* the pattern in the case matches. If the guard expression evaluates to true, the pattern match succeeds.

In the second case, when the pattern in the case matches, a partial function is executed. Within that partial function body is a condition, and this works out like any function body with a condition inside.

Check out Section 8.4 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for details on pattern matching. It is riveting.

Finally, note both your examples will produce errors or warnings (depending on Scala version) because the defaults are unreachable. I know it is just a contrived example, but just sayin'.

Comment: There are no partial functions at play in the 2nd example (w/o the guard). Partial function literals look exactly like match bodies but when `match` is used, the block of cases is compiled in-line.

Comment: Hmm that is at odds with what I've read. Not that I'm doubting you. Can you point out a resource? And also, feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: It is the case that much earlier in Scala's now 10-year history the match construct was based on partial functions, that has not been so for at least about 5 years as I understand it. Also, I wanted to edit my comment but missed the five-minute cutoff. Neither of the snippets of code in the question involve partial function literals. One other thing: Unreachable cases do not produce compile errors.

Comment: I just meant editing my answer rather than your comment. I've had a heck of a time finding anything on this topic. But ten years? Really? Man, I'm old. It's like seeing someone I remember watching play as a college athlete become a coach.

Comment: As for the compile error, I found an "unreachable code" error when I ran the code in Scala 2.9.3. But only a warning in 2.10.3. Edit made.

Comment: @RandallSchulz s/partial function literal/pattern matching anonymous function/. http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/6456.html

Comment: I'm not sure your point, but "pattern matching anonymous function" does not appear on that page while its title is "Partial Function Literal."

Comment: @RandallSchulz The title of the thread is "Partial Function Literal?" because there is no such thing per se. The case block is either a Function or PF depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

8.4 of the spec says evaluation of expressions may not be in textual order, which is why guards should not be side-effecting.

So if your conditional test is side-effecting, don't put it in a guard.